# Disparity in View Page Source and View in Firebug

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firebug

I want to know how these analytics and advertisers are called from **'online.wsj.com' HTML** source. Upto the following point, HTML code in Firebug is consistent with the one in I accessed via 'view source page'.

Firefox view source page:

```
<'!--[if IE 8]><'link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sc.wsj.net/djstyle/1/ie8/ASIA_WSJ/0_0_WAH_0001_public-20140522122816.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<'script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8"><!--
var userName = '(none)';
```

Firebug:

```
<'!-- [if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sc.w… -->

<'script type="text/javascript" src="http://beacon.krxd.net/optout_check?callback=Krux.ns._default.kxjsonp_optOutCheck"><'/script>
<'script async="" src="//cdn.krxd.net/ctjs/controltag.js.36fec01aa23444783514e74efb6b7d64"><'/script>
<'script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://cdn.cxense.com/cx.js"><'/script>
```

Is it 'jsexec' calling these third-party domains?

PS: I am newbie to web-programming and I would highly appreciate you kind input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *View Page Source* option in Firefox shows you the raw HTML source as it came from the server.

The [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) inside Firebug on the other side provides a live view on the HTML source. That means it is updated on changes done to the HTML structure through JavaScript.

These changes can also be expanded and highlighted within the panel checking the options *Highlight Changes* and *Expand Changes* within the *HTML* panel options menu:

[image: Expand and highlight HTML changes within Firebug]

To answer your question: Yes, the third-party scripts are added dynamically via JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, I am wondering how and what part of 'source page' include these scripts, dynamically.

Comment: That should be asked as a separate question as this question was just about how to find out whether the scripts are dynamically added.